# funcion multiCallBacks

Tags: callback

Estoy aprendiendo Javascript y me tope con un ejercicio que no se como resolver!! No se si podran ayudarme! gracias! Les dejo el enunciado:

```
// la funcion multiCallbacks recibe dos arrays de objetos cuyas propiedades son dos,
// 'cb' que es una funcion, y 'time' que es el tiempo estimado de ejecucion de dicha funcion 
// este ultimo representado con un integer como se muestra acontinuacion:
// let cbsExample = [
//     {cb:function(){}, time: 2},
//     {cb:function(){}, time: 3}
// ]
// De manera que lo que nuestra funcion 'multiCallbacks' debe de ir ejecutando las funciones 
// sin pasarle parametros pero debe ir alternando las funciones de cbs1 y cbs2 
// segun cual de estas se estima que tarde menos, retornando un arreglo de resultados
// de las mismas en el orden que fueron ejecutadas
// Ejemplo:
// > let cbs1 = [
//       {cb:function(){return '1-1'}, time: 2},
//       {cb:function(){return '1-2'}, time: 3}
//   ];
// > let cbs2 = [
//       {cb:function(){return '2-1'}, time: 1},
//       {cb:function(){return '2-2'}, time: 4}
//   ];
// > multiCallbacks(cbs1, cbs2);
// < ["2-1", "1-1", "1-2", "2-2"];
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Tu pregunta parece que nos pides que hagamos el ejercicio por ti. Debes aportar el código de lo que has intentado hacer por tu cuenta. Puedes leer [mcve]. Tu pregunta puede terminar cerrada. Saludos

Comment: Tu consulta es muy genérica; no nos dice cual es tu dificultad.